# remove index.php file in CI ubuntu 12.04

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the index.php file from file path in CI . I am using ubuntu 12.04  . I tried almost all the forum result but no sucess .

I place the CI folder at this path .

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/
```

I have apache rewrite mod enable .

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
Module rewrite already enabled
```

I also have this in my conf.php file

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/xxx/CI/'; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['index_url'] = '';
```

I have this in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

.htaccess file is at this path

```
http://localhost/xxx/CI/.htaccess
```

and it is enable too through apache

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
AllowOverride All
```

I get this error when i access the file like this

```
 http://localhost/xxx/CI/login/
 404 Error
 The requested URL /xxx/CI/login/ was not found on this server.
```

Any help will be appreciated  .

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting 404 errors? And where is your `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: yes mike i get 404 error . my .htaccess file is at this path 
http://localhost/xxx/CI/.htaccess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `.htaccess` file below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xxx/CI/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]
```

Then, change your `uri_protocol` from `AUTO` to `PATH_INFO`:

```php
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

If that starts re-routing everything to the default controller, then change it to `ORIG_PATH_INFO`:

```php
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';
```

**Additional Information**

Insert these lines into your file:

```
Options -Multiviews +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: i really appreciate your reply ,i did exactly what you said but still its not working and give me 404 error . First i change the uri_protocol to PATH_INFO and it shows me 404 error than i change it to ORIG_PATH_INFO it again show me 404 error :(

Comment: I have this earlier in this file 
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default

Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
I change to this according to your message still 404 error , i restarted the apache too .

Comment: Is that an actual configuration file? Have you tried putting it in `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: now 404 error is removed but whatever page i access it show me only same view .

Comment: So, for every route you try to access, is it showing the view for the `xxx/CI/` route (i.e. the default controller)?

Comment: if that is the case, please change the `uri_protocol` back to `AUTO`.

Comment: xxx/CI/ here it shows me file from view and i have no idea how its showing that file . but when i try to access any other link it always pick the site controller and load its view , i comment the loading of view and now it dont show that view and now every link it shows me blank page

Comment: +1 I think the problem was with the options. Good. Shouldn't the URI-path be passed to `index.php`, as in the question?

Comment: Well, CodeIgniter should pick up the URL anyway, from the `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: @faa i dont understand you , and i havnt did any changes to config.php file except this $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';

Comment: @user1224233 I was asking Mike if passing the URI-path in his answer, like in your question (`index.php/$0`) was not necessary.

Comment: i did one change , i reverse the value of uri_protocol $config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
and now its working smoothly and every page redirecting ok . BIG THANKS TO ALL :)

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /xxx/CI/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/index.php/$1 [L]
```

And check "rewrite_module" of apache must be enabled.

and index_page in your config should be blank
$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work , yes apache rewrite_module is enabled too and this is true too $config['index.php'] ='';

Comment: i putt this in RewriteBase /var/www/xxx/CI/

Comment: i change the RewriteBase to this xxx/CI/ but still same problem , i even restarted apache too .

Comment: i tried that but no luck ,  i tried both lines one by one but nothing happen  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/xxx/CI/index.php/$1 [L]/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xxx/CI/index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this code in your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```